# How to display top 10 records by number of accesses

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am building a report to display the Top 10 Applications by number of Accesses in the past month. So far I've wrote this code:

```
Select
Top 10 r.Displayname, Count(Distinct(ur.EntryDtm)) as AccessCount
from Table1 ur, Table2 r
where ur.EntryDtm between 
  (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())-1,0))
   and 
  (DATEADD(MONTH,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))
and r.AppID = ur.AppID
group by r.Displayname
order by 2 desc
```

This only displays only 1 record (example output below):

```
Displayname|AccessCount
-----------------------
   App 1   |    26
```

What am I missing to return the top 10 Apps, as opposed to just the most accessed app? When I go and view the records manually in MS SQL Server, there is other applications there, but they are not appearing when running my query.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: be sure that the query return more that 1 rows .. (try for test removing Top 10)

Comment: You query looks fine (except for the date magic stuff which I didn't verify). Please provide a [mcve] with test data.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I dont know why you JOIN the `database` table with itself. Looks like a simple group by should do the job. Also dont name a table `database`

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: Thank you all for the replys! @scaisEdge -  I removed top 10 and the result is the same :( . JuanCarlos - I have edited my inital post, I am pulling info from 2 different tables but my example didn't show that, my apologies!

Comment: @Frank-NewToThis  don't worry  .. try  eval your where condition why return so few rows  (without group by)

Comment: I found the issue within the Where condition!The issue was a silly mistake on my part,  leaving in a condition from a previous query without noticing that was only met by that one record. Thank you for your time and effort!